# How do I call an alert inside AJAX using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new to web development. I've been stuck in this issue for quite some time, regarding calling an alert inside my AJAX. All I want to do is show an alert to the user, if no records are found in my database. My code is as follwing:

**Javascript:**

```
function get_types() {

    let $select = $("#colony_type");

    $.ajax({
      url: 'server.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "input": "types",
              "name": $("#colony_name").val() }, 
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(response) {
        let selectedValue = $select.val();
        let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
        $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
      },

      complete: function() {}
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $pass="";

    $con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$pass);
    $connection=mysqli_select_db($con,"electric billing system");

    if($_POST["input"] == "types"){

            if(!$connection)
                    echo "Connection to database failed! Please try again";
            else{
                    $codes=array();
                    $sql = "SELECT * from colony_master WHERE Colony_name='".$_POST["name"]."'";
                    $result = $con->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $code=$row["Colony_code"];
                            }
                            $sql = "SELECT * from quarter_master_entry WHERE Colony_code='".$code."'";
                            $result = $con->query($sql);
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    array_push($codes,$row["Qtr_type"]);
                                }
                                echo json_encode($codes);
                            }
                            else
                               echo "No colony type information found"; //I want to show this message as alert if no records are found
                            
                    }
                   
            }
        }

        $con->close();
 ?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="cln_type"><b>Type</b> :<br><select name="colony_type" id="colony_type" onclick="get_types()">
                <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your colony type</option>
</select></p>
```

If I receive an empty array from the server, then it should show an alert. How do I do that? Please help me.

---

**EDIT:** I've tried showing an alert message using this code inside my `else` statement in php, but still doesn't work:

```
$message = "No colony type information found";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
```

Comment: You never will receive an empty array. You will receive a string `"No colony type information found"`

Comment: Fast fix: In `success`, `if(typeof(response)=="string"){alert(response)}`

Comment: In an `else` block, you probably should `JSON.parse(response)`...

Comment: The difficulty here is your request may end up in a JSON or a string. Better fix the server-side part so it always output the same type as a response. That is the first step to be clean.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the server-side response so it aways answer with a jsonified array

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($codes,$row["Qtr_type"]);
  }
  //echo json_encode($codes);
}else{
  $error=array();
  $error['error'] = "No colony type information found";
  array_push($codes,$error);
}
echo json_encode($codes);
```

Then in the ajax `success`:

```
success: function(response) {
  let selectedValue = $select.val();
  
  response = JSON.parse(response); // Possibly useless... Just as a note. 

  if(response.error){
    alert(response.error)
    return
  }
  
  let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
  $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
},
```

Untested... But you should get the point. ;)

Comment: Likely need to join() the array of html strings. html() works fine with array of elements or jq objects but doubt it will with string array without unwanted `,`

Comment: Mehh... That is just a suggestion to point in a direction. Not a perfect solution. A late saturday thing ;)

Comment: It shows an error: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` in the line `response=JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Ok then squarely remove that line. the token `o` certainly is the `o` of "object"...  Since you specified `dataType: 'json',` Ajax has done the parsing already. ;)

Comment: Now it shows `[Object object]` when I click on it. Nevertheless, there's still no alert